# How to paginate with NG-ZORRO-Andt in Angular

Tags: html, angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I want to use NG-ZORRO-andt pagination in the Html page, it's showing in my browser but how do I link the data from the api with the pagination?

This is my Html code

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" *ngFor="let course of peopleHome"> //I want to paginate this data
        <div class="card-blog">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="../assets/images/image10.jpg" alt="" class="img-blog" />
            </a>
            <div class="card">
                <a href="#">
                    <h4 class="title-blog">{{course.people_title}}</h4>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nz-pagination [nzPageIndex]="1" [nzTotal]="peopleHome.length" [nzPageSize]="10"> </nz-pagination>
</div>
```

So please how can i link my response to nz-pagination?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `nz-pagination` without any work with your array. How an array should understand that you want to get a part of it? There is two option to paginate your array:

1. Use nz-table
2. Use `(nzPageIndexChange)` and `(nzPageSizeChange)` methods of `nz-pagination` to filter your array